# NUXT3 VUE3 : How to pass local img src path to vue component in a nuxt project

Tags: image, vuejs3, require, src

I am passing url to local images stored in the `~/assets/img` folder to a Vue3 component, but I am not able to render them by any means.

THIS WORKS

```
<img
  src="~/assets/img/tds_logo.png"
/>
```

BUT THIS DOES NOT WORK

```
<img
  :src="require(`~/assets/img/` + fileName)"
/>
```

the last literal `fileName` is something I am passing to a Vue component to render the img and I have checked that that is equal to `tds_logo.png` in my case.

Instead I get this error:
`[nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] Error: Cannot find module '~/assets/img/tds_logo.png'`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

As per this https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets/ I shouldn't need to configure anything, right?

Comment: Have a look at [what is `require()` in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9901097/4883195). If you actually want to load the image as a module, you need to have proper loaders and load the image at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Vite does not have inbuilt `require` like webpack and only has import.

In Nuxt3 / Vue3

write a method for the component like below:

```
 props: ['imagename'],
 methods: {
    getImageUrl(imagename) {
      const imageUrl = new URL(`/assets/img/${imagename}`, import.meta.url).href
      return imageUrl;

    }
  }
```

and then use this method in the template:

```
<img
:src="getImageUrl(imagename)"
  
/>
```