# I can't understand the difference between the static and assets folder in Nuxt.js 3

Tags: nuxtjs3

I read documentation, googled similar questions, and even asked AI and anyway didn't understand the difference between static and assets folder in Nuxt 3. I can use Sass styles in the static folder, and it's working very well. Also, I used images, JSONs, and TypeScript files both in the static and assets folder, everything is similar. Why do I even need an assets folder? For compilation? Everything is working similarly in the static folder. If you know, can you tell me more clearly so I can understand? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NUXT- assets and static folder - when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808182/nuxt-assets-and-static-folder-when-to-use-which)

Comment: @Marc, no, I saw that post, didn't understand the difference, static and assets folders working both well, I want to know the edge when to use static and when to use assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is supposed to be processed by the compiler should be in the `assets` folder and by default that tends to be style sheets weather its, LESS SASS or PostCSS, so on and so forth.

Stylesheets that do not need any processing of any kind can go in `static`, for example `animate.css` from https://animate.style/, lets say you simply downloaded:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css
because you want to host it your self rather than installing it via NPM package or instead of using the CDN Url, this is when you should put a pre-processed & minified (already compiled) `css` file in the `static` folder because there is no need for the build tools to waste valuable CI-CD build time doing unnecessary processing on such files.

Anything in the `static` folder should not be processed (or it is not supposed to be) saving you $$$ in pipeline costs because those resources do not eat up built time minutes.

You might see content from within `static` appearing to be processed because it will have been `imported` or `required` by a source file that is in the scope of the `assets` folder or in the scope of any build configuration targeting sources outside of `assets` directory.

**When might you stick images into the `assets` folder?**

You might install & configure various image processors that do things like, generate multiple size sets for desktop and mobile or optimize images encoding to reduce file size, or convert `jpg` & `png` images to `webp`.
This is when you put `images` in `assets` because the build tools are going to process and alter them.

Therefore any images that are not going to be altered in any way and are to be published `as-is` should go in the `static` folder.

**When might you put a `static` source into `assets` dir?**

Let's say you want to ensure a particular asset is not cached by the users browser, you alter an image previously published and want to ensure users now see the updated image not the old cached image without altering the filename your self to ensure it is newly loaded.

You can leverage file name hashing within `assets`,a hash number is generated based on the file content, if the content changes then so does the hash value on the next build else it stays the same as the previous production build, the hash string is injected into the filename ensuring users always get fresh content not cached content and the dynamically generated filename is automatically written to the final output of your Vue templates and CSS files where they have made reference to `assets`.

Comment: You answered as clearly as I wanted. I understood now. Thank you so much!